# How to execute multiple depent SQLite Queries (Run SQLite Script) from Java?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have some data in an SQLite Database. The following queries in SQLiteBrowser give me exactly the ResultSet I want:

```
With TempTable0 AS (SELECT Source, Date, Value AS Close FROM FinData WHERE Type = 'Close'),
TempTable1 AS (SELECT Source, Date, Value AS  Colume FROM FinData WHERE Type = ' Colume')

SELECT DISTINCT TempTable0.Date,  Close,   Colume  FROM TempTable0 
JOIN TempTable1 ON TempTable1.Date = TempTable0.Date
```

Now, I tried to get this working as a single query via a simple `executeQuery`-Method from Java and read the data in a Matrixlike-DataStructure:

```
String sql = "With TempTable0 AS (SELECT Source, Date, Value AS Close FROM FinData WHERE Type = 'Close'), TempTable1 AS (SELECT Source, Date, Value AS  Colume FROM FinData WHERE Type = ' Colume') SELECT DISTINCT TempTable0.Date,  Close,   Colume  FROM TempTable0 JOIN TempTable1 ON TempTable1.Date = TempTable0.Date";

Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(SQLCommunication.urlDB);
Statement stmt = Conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

while (rs.next() ) {

    String res = rs.getString("Close");
    DataMatrix.get("Close").add(res);

    res = rs.getString("Colume");
    DataMatrix.get("Colume").add(res);

    }
```

However, the Resultset returns `null`.
I suspect this is because, it cannot work with two dependent SQLite-Queries, however, I have no idea, how to solve this.

I am no expert on SQLite and Java interaction and I am really running out of ideas, right now. Do you have any sugestions? (Even maybe a tip on nesting these two statements in one so it can be executed in one shot?)

Thanks so much!

Wiwi

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and then edit your question

Comment: Thanks for the note. Enriched the post.

Comment: You really want to make this an [mcve] to make it easy for others to reproduce it. As importantly, there is little in your question that describes your schema, the data you have in it, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you have a space before Colume in Type = ' Colume'?

Comment: BTW the sql can be simplified to `SELECT DISTINCT F0.Date,  F0.Value AS Close,   F1.Value AS Colume FROM FinData F0, FinData F1 WHERE F0.Type = 'Close' AND F1.Type = ' Colume' AND F0.Date = F1.Date`

Comment: What is the value of `urlDB`?

Comment: Thanks so much. I have solved the question. Dabiuteef's answer really helped.